# Bash script to open new terminal with path from current?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am using zsh
For example, i am in ~/Downloads, and want to run script, that will run new terminal with this path.

What i did.
work.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
current_path="$PWD"
echo $current_path | xclip -selection clipboard
xfce4-terminal -e "zsh -c 'cd ~/Documents/bash/bash-scripts; ./work-test.sh; zsh'"
```

work-test.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

script_path=$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)
echo $script_path
sleep 1
cd "$script_path"
```

Run script with

```
source ~/Documents/bash/bash-scripts/work.sh
```

But don't work.

Answer (score 3):

`xfce4-terminal` already carries the current directory through to a new instance.

Example

```
# Terminal session 1
cd /tmp
xfce4-terminal &

# New terminal session 2
pwd
/tmp

# Back to terminal session 1
cd
xfce4-terminal &

# New terminal session 3
pwd
/home/chris
```

If typing `xfce4-terminal &` is too much there's nothing stopping you creating a function or alias. For example, this function is invoked as `xt`

```
xt() { xfce4-terminal "$@" & }
```